# React Navigation switch to same navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using React Native 0.63, Expo 40, and React Navigation 5. I have the following as a functional component inside my Navigation Container - a literal switch navigator:

```
switch (appState) {
    case 'StateA':
        return <FirstStackNavigator/>;
    case 'StateB':
        return <SecondStackNavigator optionValue={true}/>;
    case 'StateC':
        return <SecondStackNavigator optionValue={false}/>;
    case 'StateD':
        return <ThirdStackNavigator />
}
```

And this is my SecondStackNavigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="FirstRoute" component={FirstScreen} initialParams={{ option: optionValue }} />
    ...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Depending on a number of things behind the scenes, the app transitions through state A-D or skips over states entirely - kind of a complex onboarding process.

My issue is the transition from StateB to StateC. Nothing visibly happens when the state transition happens, and I think I understand why - the same navigator is used, so RN just leaves the hierarchy alone. Fair enough.

However, I want a brand new SecondStackNavigator used with StateC, with the first page on the stack so we can follow that navigator again with the new option.

I've tried using keys on the screens and navigators, with no real luck. Am I missing some fundamental of React Navigation, or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky suggestion, what if you wrapped the navigator under StateB in a View like so:

```
switch (appState) {
    case 'StateA':
        return <FirstStackNavigator/>;
    case 'StateB':
    // here
        return (
            <View>
                <SecondStackNavigator optionValue={true}/>;
            </View>
        );
    case 'StateC':
        return <SecondStackNavigator optionValue={false}/>;
    case 'StateD':
        return <ThirdStackNavigator />
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but no luck. It gives me the same behavior. I think RN5 is "smart" enough to see the same navigator. I've tried a few variations of View as well.